# Windows 7 professional Networking query using Sky Broadband and NAS

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, nas

I have a D-Link NAS which was working happily thru an EE BrightHub. It could access the internet whilst the PC was switched off.

I have changed from EE to Sky and find an issue with the Sky hub. It is a known problem whereby the router cannot recognise anything connected on an ethernet cable if it is using wifi. This is due to it not using zeroconf I think.

So I reconnected Brighthub to the NAS using an ethernet cable and the NAS is visible on Brighthub wifi.  Connect NAS using same ethernet cable and the Sky box and it is simply invisible on SKy WIFI.

So I want the NAS to be able to access the Sky internet and for the PC to be able to see the NAS files  using  wifi and also have broadband.

Sky do not allow you to use a different router from their issued router to access the internet. They also say they have fulfilled thir contract as I have broadband and the router  issue is my problem.

How do I connect my Brighthub to my Sky router ? I'm trying using an ethernet cable between the two routers with the Brighthub doing wifi and the Sky Hub accessing the internet. the Skyhub has wifi switched off and DHCP on whilst the brighthub has WIFI on and  DHCP switched off. The NAS would be connected to the Brighthub.

Should this work allowing me to access the internet on PC and NAS and the NAS accessible on PC  too ?

the addresses are 
Sky hub 192.168.0.1
Brighthub 192.168.1.1

the Sky hub does not allow you to modify the address range.

any help much appreciated on how to set this up or an alternative approach :)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your D-Link NAS remembers (or you've manually set a static IP) an IP address that's outside the subnet of what your Sky Hub is currently in.

In other words, it's very likely that the problem lies in your NAS' settings. You don't need to connect the EE Bright Hub to the Sky Hub in order to gain access to your NAS. It's probably possible to do it that way, but it's a complexity not worth getting into.

Here's a few things to try:

1. Disconnect the NAS from your network.
2. Verify that DHCP is turned on.
3. (Optional) Reboot the device.
4. Connect it to the Sky Hub.
5. Search for the NAS' IP in the Sky Hub.
6. (Optional) If the Sky Hub has an IP reservation feature, reserve an IP for your NAS.